# iphone and glaxy s3 css media query together in same css not working properly

Tags: android, html, iphone, css, media-queries

i tried the following css Media queries in my css file for adjusting size and position  of 2 images in div.but its not working properly ,eventhough i have given the correct parameters in media query.I am creating mobile webpage (HTML5,CSS,JS) targetting on Iphone blackberry,android & windows devices.

my css media query for s3 is as follows..

```
  @media only screen and (device-width:360px) and (device-height:640px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation : portrait) 
  {
 #image1{height:45%;width:42%;margin-left:2%;margin-top:2%;float:left;}

  #image2{height:55%;width:55%;margin-right:0px;margin-    top:0;float:right;position:relative;z-index:3;}
   }
```

my css media query for iphone 3 gen is as follows

```
  @media only screen and (device-width:320px) and (device-height:480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation : portrait) 
  {
 #image1{height:77%;width:42%;margin-left:2%;margin-top:2%;float:left;}

  #image2{height:100%;width:55%;margin-right:0px;margin-    top:0;float:right;position:relative;z-index:3;}
   }
```

The problem i am facing here is in iphone 3 the css for galaxy s3 is getting loaded. i tried with this code also for s3 ,

```
   @media only screen and (min-device-width:720px) and (max-device-width:1280px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation : portrait) 
  {
 #image1{height:45%;width:42%;margin-left:2%;margin-top:2%;float:left;}

  #image2{height:55%;width:55%;margin-right:0px;margin-    top:0;float:right;position:relative;z-index:3;}
   }
```

sadly the result was same in iphone .what should i do here.is there any good references for targetting multiple mobile platform with CSS